# How to find response time for a given journal in engineering?

Tags: journals, peer-review

I would like to find journals response times? A google search does not give any good results. May be I am using wrong key words.

I am open to find particular subset of journal response times too. Any pointers about this is welcome. [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/904/333) gives a list of backlog for mathematical journals. Are there any such other list? How can I find them?

Thanks for comment.
Actually I would like to learn "From submission until a decision". I know "Total time from submission to publication" can take a lot of time.

Comment: What do you mean by "response time"?  Total time from submission to publication?  From submission until a decision?  (Incidentally, the variance in these times can be enormous even at a single journal, so the average is just a rough guide.)

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician thanks, I edited question

Answer (score 9):

Some journals insert the submission date and acceptance date in a footnote on the first page of the article.  For those, it would be easy to look through the latest issue and see what is typical.

Answer (score 3):

I would send an email, or ideally go down the hall, and ask someone who has published in the journal how long it took.

Comment: This is better than nothing, but one data point can sometimes be very misleading.